# Creating a simple macro in VBA -- using text in cell as address

Tags: excel, vba

I'm building a financial worksheet, which does some simple math.

I want to do a simple Copy+Paste, but specifying the paste path with information contained in a certain cell. I can get the desired path according to a variable TICKER using a formula (as shown the image), but I can't insert this "variable path", contained in a cell, into VBA.

The "copy" values are in blue.
The desired (dynamic) destinations are in yellow.
By the way, the destination sheet isn't the same, but it's in the same workbook.

The intention is to overwrite the price in the destination cell (as an update system).

[image: in this image]

This is the code I was using:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim xSheet As Worksheet
    Set xSheet = ActiveSheet
        If xSheet.Name <> "Definitions" And xSheet.Name <> "fx" And xSheet.Name <> "Needs" Then
            xSheet.Range("G31").Copy
            xSheet.Range("(J31)").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: `xSheet.Range(Range("J31").Value).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=...` will take the text in `J31` and use it as the range address to paste to

Comment: Perfect, that works, thank you!

But how to assign this exact value to make it go to the other sheet? 
I tried inserting _'Sheet_name'!_ in front of it, no sucess.

Comment: That would be `Worksheets("Sheet_Name").Range(xSheet.Range("J31").Value).PasteSpecial ...`

Comment: Wonderful, that's exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much.